# SharePoint 2019 rest search api not working

Tags: sharepoint-server, development, search, crawling

My scenario: I am having an issue that if i try to search for a content in a file it returns null. I have make sure to manually re index both the site and the list.

I have then force a manual crawling for the search service application. Still when i run the below code,i get a zero results. can you guys help here. Even if search for a word found in a document on SharePoint search bar it return no result

```
 private static void secondtest()
    {
        var siteUrl = "http://sharepoint/sites/test/";
       // var listName = "Documents";
        var loginName = @"test\admin";
        var password = "password";
        var querytext = "SharePoint";
      //  HttpWebRequest endpointRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(siteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('" + listName + "')/items");
       // HttpWebRequest endpointRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(siteUrl + "_api/search/query?querytext='"+querytext+"'");
        HttpWebRequest endpointRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(siteUrl + "_api/search/suggest?querytext='" + querytext + "'");

        endpointRequest.Method = "GET";
        endpointRequest.Accept = "application/json;odata=verbose";
        NetworkCredential cred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(loginName, password);
        endpointRequest.Credentials = cred;
        HttpWebResponse endpointResponse = (HttpWebResponse)endpointRequest.GetResponse();
        try
        {
            WebResponse webResponse = endpointRequest.GetResponse();
            Stream webStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(webStream);
            string response = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
            JObject jobj = JObject.Parse(response);
            JArray jarr = (JArray)jobj["d"]["results"];

            foreach (JObject j in jarr)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(j["Title"]);
            }
            responseReader.Close();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine(e.Message); Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do queries for the account you are using in your app work in the search center?

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott Yes, i have use another piece of code it is working perfectly,but this one doesn't work

Comment: Do you have suggestions registered in this farm?